# Create a event with "Out of Office"

Tags: scripting, event-handling, google-calendar-api

When I create a event in my calendar I have the option "Out of Office". How I can create a event about GScript with the function "Out of Office"?

[image: Add a Event]

Here you can find my current sheet incl. my script: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17zdmhWr9EUrY_-6ZVrYWggf5kAnvEhKGdGsJbxW7Px4/edit?usp=sharing

How can I add the command? or is there a feature which I do not know?

Answer (score 1):

#### Answer:

*Unfortunately, in its current form, this isn't possible through the Calendar API.*

#### More Information:

Google Apps Script and the G Suite service integration it provides are effectively wrappers for the already existing APIs for the services they connect to (Calendar, Sheets, Docs, etc). As a result, given that the feature is not available through the API, Apps Script does not have this ability either.

#### Feature Request:

I did a search on Google's Issue Tracker and there are a couple of highly requested Feature Requests for the creation of Out of office events through the Calendar API already.

You can find these Feature Requests [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/112063903) and [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/122674818), which you can give a star (☆) in the top left to let Google know more people wish for this request to be implemented.